# Fetch database values to select option tag using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to set db values into select option tag and show them in drop down list using Rails 3. Suppose User model has 5 fields and i need all name column value of User model  will set into drop down list in a select option tag.When page will be loaded(i.e-home.html.erb) all name field values should fetch from DB and set in select tag.Please help me to resolve this issue.

## Home.html.erb:

```
<div class="block-title"><h5>Office Use</h5></div>
            <div class="block-content full">
                    <div class="totalaligndiv">
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6" style="margin:auto; float:none;"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Select Vendor :</div></span>
                        <select class="form-control">
                          <option selected>Selected Vendor</option>
                          <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="clearfix"></div>
                      <div class="tbpaddingdiv1 text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add to payment</button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div
```

Please help me.

Comment: How you render this `home` template? Do you want to use dropdown in form?

Comment: @Gagan:the first page is home page.Before values are in DB.When user will open this page only name culumn value of User model will display in a drop down list.

Comment: Let me to add the some template code.

Comment: @Gagan:Yes but something i am missing but your answer was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Replace this code

```
<select class="form-control">
   <option selected>Selected Vendor</option>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
</select>
```

with

```
<%= select_tag "User", options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, :id, :name), , {:class=>'form-control', :prompt => 'Selected Vendor'}  %>
```

for more details : http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag

Comment: for instance with 10 000 users, this gets extremely slow and barely usable

Comment: now I need to figure out how to make a dynamic select, maybe with `datalist`